# How to add logs in RHPAM DMN?

Tags: dmn, rhpam

I need help in RHPAM Business Central.

Anybody knows how to add any print statements or logs in DMN's for debugging DMN flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own `DMNRuntimeEventListener`.

The listener is usually wired in Drools library using: [https://docs.drools.org/8.33.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/DMN/index.html#dmn-properties-ref_dmn-models:~:text=org.kie.dmn.runtime.listeners.%24LISTENER_NAME](https://docs.drools.org/8.33.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/DMN/index.html#dmn-properties-ref_dmn-models:%7E:text=org.kie.dmn.runtime.listeners.%24LISTENER_NAME)

e.g.: with a configuration such as:

```
-Dorg.kie.dmn.runtime.listeners.mylistener=org.acme.MyDMNListener
```

or alternatively with analogous configuration in `kmodule.xml`

```xml
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
  <configuration>
    <property key="org.kie.dmn.runtime.listeners.mylistener" value="org.acme.MyDMNListener"/>
  </configuration>
</kmodule>
```

This latter option, is the one you might preference on *RHPAM Business Central*.

You might find helpful this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzstCC3Df0Q